# Handlebars bind outside each in markup

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js, each, bind

I have a problem to bind an object in handlebars outside each "sectorsPressCoverageElements" in a markup.
This is my data that is a json:

```
{
  "name": "Rassegna",
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 7,
  "sectorsPressCoverageElements": [
    {
      "id": 25129,
      "media": "media",
      "linkMedia": "",
      "article": "article",
      "journalist": "",
      "linkJournalist": "",
      "publishingDate": "2017-11-23T09:00:00",
      "purchase": false
    },
    {
      "id": 25129,
      "media": "media",
      "linkMedia": "",
      "article": "article",
      "journalist": "",
      "linkJournalist": "",
      "publishingDate": "2017-11-23T09:00:00",
      "purchase": false
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

My problem is bind "name" that is outside each. 
This my markup with area to bind "data-name" with name (for example in json : "name": "Rassegna"):

```
<script id="handlePressCoverage" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each sectorsPressCoverageElements}}
    <tr data-id="{{id}}" data-category="0">
        @*<td> <input type="checkbox" class="select-element"></td>*@
        <td class="col-xs-2">{{#simplifyDate publishingDate}}{{/simplifyDate}}</td>    
            <text>
                <td class="col-xs-1"><button data-id="{{id}}" data-name="{{HOW BIND NAME HERE??}}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs iPressShare">Save &nbsp<i class="iPressIconShare fas fa-share-alt"></i></button></td>
            </text>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

And pass data to handlebars:

```
var sourcePressCoverage = $("#handlePressCoverage").html();
var templatePressCoverage = Handlebars.compile(sourcePressCoverage);
           $.getJSON(url, function (data) {    
                $htmlsourcePressCoverage = $(templatePressCoverage(data));              
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind `name` that is outside `each`, You can use `../ segments` in Handlebar. This will evaluate their paths against a parent context.

For example in your case simply putting `../name` in the `data-name` attribute will result in `Rassegna`

```
<script id="handlePressCoverage" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each sectorsPressCoverageElements}}
<tr data-id="{{id}}" data-category="0">
    @*<td> <input type="checkbox" class="select-element"></td>*@
    <td class="col-xs-2">{{#simplifyDate publishingDate}}{{/simplifyDate}}</td>    
        <text>
            <td class="col-xs-1"><button data-id="{{id}}" data-name="{{../name}}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs iPressShare">Save &nbsp<i class="iPressIconShare fas fa-share-alt"></i></button></td>
        </text>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The correct bind is data-name="{{../name}}" . Thank you very much!

Comment: To make this post more complete, is there a solution even for cases where you want to bind two different data json in a markup? Thank you very much